# Can't identify source of text boxes in template

Tags: hyperref, varioref

I'm working with this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/geoscience-masters-thesis/rdwnkmgfkjnx). I can't seem to figure out how to remove some of the unwanted boxes, e.g. under the Abstract, there's a grey box that reads "Add new section about results in Chapter 4" or under Appendix A there's a white box with black border that reads "sec:first-app". I've fiddled with the code in `main.tex` and `style.sty`, but can't seem to locate the source(s) of these boxes. I'm wondering if these boxes are associated with `varioref` and `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1):

The grey box in the abstract comes from the following line

```
\todo[inline]{Add new section about results in \cref{sec:fourth}.}
```

in the code of `abstract.tex`:

```
\abstractintoc % Add abstract to Table of Contents  
\abstractnum   % Format abstract like a chapter
               % Remove if abstract should not be on its own page

\begin{abstract}
    \kant[1] % Dummy text
    \todo[inline]{Add new section about results in \cref{sec:fourth}.}
\end{abstract}
```

with the result:

[image: abstract]

To get rid of this line and the others simply delete/comment the line(s) with command `\todo` ...